# URLs in mailer view files using namespaces and custom member actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, routes, namespaces

I am running Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to use URLs *in mailer view files* with *namespaces* and *custom member actions*. I read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views) but I have still problems on implementing that.

In `routes.rb` I have:

```
namespace "users" do
  resources :accounts do
    member do
      get 'my_action_name'
      post 'my_action_name'
    end
  end
end
```

In `users_mailer.rb` I have:

```
class Users::Accounts < ActionMailer::Base
  default_url_options[:host] = "test_name_site.com"

  def account_delete(account)
    @account = account
    @action_url = users_account_url(:controller => "users/accounts", :action => "my_action_name")
    ...
  end
end
```

When in the controller I try to do this:

```
@account = Users::Account.find(params[:id])
Users::Accounts.account_delete(Users::Account.find_by_id(@account.id)).deliver
```

I get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"my_action_name", :controller=>"users/accounts"})
```

**How I can solve that?**

---

In `users_mailer.rb` I tryed also

```
# the difference is: from 'users_account_url' to 'users_accounts_url'
@action_url = users_accounts_url(:controller => "users/account_authentications", :action => "confirm_account_authentication_delete")

# the difference is: from 'users_account_url' to 'url_for'
@action_url = url_for(:controller => "users/account_authentications", :action => "confirm_account_authentication_delete")
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specify an ID of a record in users_account_url
try this

```
@action_url = my_action_name_users_account_url(account)
```

http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/accounts/1/my_action_name

[Routing gude](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls)

Comment: I did not understand. Can you make an example starting from my, please?

Comment: Thanks. I was just trying your example.